# Add parameter to cookie - python requests library

Tags: python, http, cookies, request

I am using Python's [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for some web scraping. I am using the `Session()` object to retain the session throughout the chain of HTTP GET and POST requests.

I need to make an HTTP POST request like this:

```
POST http://www.examplesite.com/login HTTP/1.1
Host: www.examplesite.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 126
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www.examplesite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.examplesite.com/anon
Accept-Encoding: sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: SESS01be97003f5147af7927b0548df40bcd=qud5ra51jmtf9opnihn6tct2v0; has_js=1
```

I need to add the parameter `has_js=1` to the cookie object in the Requests session. I am not able to find any info on this specific requirement. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_js=1` is just another cookie name-value pair (most likely a [Drupal JavaScript probe cookie](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77967/what-is-the-use-of-has-js-cookie)).

All cookies your browser sends are concatenated in the one `Cookie` header, separated by `;` semicolons. Cookie parameters are part of the `Set-Cookie` header to influence what the browser does when storing the values, and never part of the `Cookie` header sent back to the server.

You can just add it to your session:

```
session.cookies['has_js'] = '1'
```